# Spring aspect call super.method() or inter method call unable to execute aspect code

Tags: java, spring-aop

I am using spring aspect -around advice;
    For super.method() or inter class method call, I am unable to call my aspect code;
    This is my code sample.

```
//My aspect Class
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Around("execution(* in.test.project.service.myservice.create(..))")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    //  . 
        //my logic
    //  .
}

public interface Myservice{
    void create(Myclass entity);
    void createObject(Myclass entity);
}

class myserviceImpl implements Myservice{
    public void create(Myclass entity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    void createObject(Myclass entity){
        create(entity);
    }
}

    class Mycontroller {
        void test(Myclass entity) {
            Myservice myservice = new myserviceImplimplements();
            // calls MyAspect code
            myservice.create(entity);

            // MyAspect not called
            myservice.createObject(entity);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a limitation of using Spring AOP without having your code know that it is using Spring AOP (you can view Spring's documentation on how you could do this as well as why you shouldn't [on their "Understanding AOP proxies" page](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)). Spring AOP is a proxy-based system and differentiates between the proxy object itself (bound to this) and the target object behind the proxy (bound to target), so you are also limited in what kinds of pointcuts you can apply.

[image: Calls are made on the proxy]

Since the call first goes through the proxy and then on the object, calls made inside of the object on that object (like the call you have above that calls a method inside) are called on the **Object itself** and not the proxy. The calls that go through the proxy can delegate to relevant interceptors, while calls that are made by the Object itself do not proxy, and thus can not be advised by Spring AOP like this. The link I provided above shows to expose the AopContext, but I would highly recommend against doing that.